# Confluence Macro: Velocity prints out unwanted "true" when using Array.add()

Tags: macros, velocity, confluence

Right now i am developing a user macro for confluence that creates a list of spaces which are in provided categories. I am new to Confluence development and i have never used Velocity before but i managed to get the macro working.

But there is one issue: Whenever i use the `.add()` method, the template prints out `true`, so what i get from the macro is a number of `true` strings + the list i want. How can i avoid the print out of `true`? Why is it printed at all?

Here's the whole macro code

```
## User Macro: spaces-in-categories
##
## Created by: Gabriel Juelke <pyriand3r@gmail.com>
## Adapted from Remo Siegwart's answer at http://web.archive.org/web/20140813094412/https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/274837/show-a-space-list-within-a-page-using-category-label
##
## @param Label:title=Space Category|type=string|required=true|desc=The categories the spaces should have. Use Pipe to separate categories.

## create list out of provided category string
#set($labelList = $paramLabel.split("\|"))
#set($spacesByLabel = [])

## try to fetch all spaces for each category
#foreach ($spaceLabel in $labelList)
  #set($label = $action.labelManager.getLabel( "team:${spaceLabel}"))
  #if ($!label)
    #$spacesByLabel.add($action.labelManager.getSpacesWithLabel( $label ))
  #else
    <div class="aui-message warning">
      <p class="title">
        <span class="aui-icon icon-warning">Warning</span>
        <strong>Space category not found</strong>
      </p>
      <p>Couldn't find space category <strong>$spaceLabel</strong>!</p>
    </div>
  #end
#end

## filter out all spaces that are not in all categories
#set($spacesInAll = [])
#set($firstList = $spacesByLabel.get(0))

#foreach ($space in $firstList)
  #set($hasAll = 1)

  #foreach ($list in $spacesByLabel)
    #set($inList = 0)

    #foreach ($item in $list)
      #if ($space.name == $item.name)
        #set($inList = 1)
      #end
    #end

    #if ($inList == 0)
      #set($hasAll = 0)
    #end

  #end

  #if ($hasAll == 1)
    #$spacesInAll.add($space);
#end

<ul class="spaces-by-category-user-macro">
#foreach ( $space in $spacesInAll )
    ## check if current user can view space
    #if ( $permissionHelper.canView( $action.getAuthenticatedUser(), $space ) )
        <li><a href="$!space.urlPath">$!space.name</a></li>
    #end
#end
</ul>

#set ( $d = "$") ## escape the dollar sign for jQuery in velocity
<script>
    ## Sort the list client side as this can't be done server side in a user macro.
    AJS.toInit(function (${d}) {
        ${d}('.spaces-by-category-user-macro').each(function(){
            var ${d}me = ${d}(this);
            // Sort the list items
            var listItems = ${d}me.children('li').get();
            listItems.sort(function(x,y) {
                var compareX = ${d}(x).text().toUpperCase();
                var compareY = ${d}(y).text().toUpperCase();
                return (compareX < compareY) ? -1 : (compareX > compareY) ? 1 : 0;
            });

            // Write the list items back to the DOM
            ${d}.each(listItems, function(index, item) { ${d}me.append(item); });
        });
    });
</script>
#end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, i have found a "workaround" i think... or the solution... but for me it seems more than a workaround:

If you encapsulate the `.add()` method in a `#set()` method you can redirect the output of the method (the `true`) into a variable which prevents it from being printed out.

So the call would look like this:

```
#set($result = $list.add($whatsoever))
```

Comment: This solved my problem, I can't help but feel there is probably a better solution though.

Answer (score 2):

I too ran into this problem and tried to come up with a solution to avoid using `#set()` along with dummy variables.  It seems that in Confluence the output of `.add()` has to be encapsulated in more Velocity code for it to not render.

This is the simplest solution I could come up with but it still makes me want to claw my eyes out:

```
#if( $array.add($data) ) #end
```